# Unable To Run My Flutter App in My iOS Device- Failed to register Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, flutter, bundle-identifier

I was trying to run the app on iOS device but then, it says Failed to register Bundle Identifier. How can this be fixed? Please check the screenshots below.

[Failed to register Bundle Identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2OUL.png)

Comment: As the error states, change your bundle identifier to something unique like `com.sharath.bhogireddy.qwert` then retry

Comment: @MidhunMP I was trying to figure out and just got away with it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Bundle Identifier` has to be unique.
You should use another identifier like `com.example.qwert` or `com.sharath.qwert`.

And also you shouldn't use a Bundle Identifier for more than on project